# Payment gateway using paypal

Tags: jsp, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, credit-card

I am creating a web app using jsp where I require to implement a payment gateway.
I got this site
 https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_test-pps-buttons/
This is similar to what I want but in this case to make a payment I should have an account on payapal and enter the email id and password to make a transaction but in my case I want to be able to enter the credit card number and CVV number.I tried finding on the same site but couldnt find anything.
Could anyone provide me with a link which could help?

Answer (score 0):

The site you are reffering https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_test-pps-buttons/ 
is used for payments via paypal only.
In case you need user directly enters Card in fos you will need a payment gateway setup. It will be costlier and will not come free you might get a few try outs but never full free.